# Url with variable for user

Tags: php

If I want to set a variable in url,

I need to send data to this url [https: //xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/rest/customers/115/credentials](http://https:%20//xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/rest/customers/115/credentials)

I want to set `$user_id` instead of `115` in url

How can I resolve it?

Thank you all for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
$url = "https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/rest/customers/$user_id/credentials";
```

or

```
$url = "https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/rest/customers/".$user_id."/credentials";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it really helped me

Answer (score 0):

simply use `.` concat operator to pass `php variable`

```
$url="https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/rest/customers/".$user_id."/credentials";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it really helped me